# Jquery calculating bouding box of a rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry

I've already looked at some other posts about that but still can't figure out why the formula isn't working.

To calculate the bounding box of a rotated rectangle :

```
w' = sin(a)*h + cos(a)*w;
h' = sin(a)*w + cos(a)*h;
```

The problem is that I'm getting weird behaviours where `w'` and `h'` are not precise at all.

```js
// calculate rotation angle of shape
function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
  var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform") ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform") ||
    obj.css("-o-transform") ||
    obj.css("transform");
  if (matrix !== 'none') {
    var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
  } else {
    var angle = 0;
  }

  if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
  return angle;
}

var shape = $('.shape'),
  shapeLeft = shape.position().left,
  shapeTop = shape.position().top,
  shapeWidth = shape.width(),
  shapeHeight = shape.height(),
  angle = getRotationDegrees(shape),
  // formula below
  height = Math.abs(shapeWidth * Math.sin(angle)) + Math.abs(shapeHeight * Math.cos(angle)),
  width = Math.abs(shapeHeight * Math.sin(angle)) + Math.abs(shapeWidth * Math.cos(angle));

$('#g1').css('width', width);
$('#g2').css('height', height);
```

```css
.elements,
.element {
  position: absolute
}

#s2 {
  background: #333333;
  top: 60px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout" style="position:relative; margin-top:50px; margin-left:70px;">
  <div class="elements">
    <div id="g1" class="element" style="background:red;left:-35px;top:-10px;height:2px;"></div>
    <div id="g2" class="element" style="background:red;left:-35px;top:-10px;width:2px;"></div>
    
    <div id="s2" class="element shape" style="transform: rotate(8deg);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Because you are doing `Math.round`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Nope, math.round is used to calculate the angle which is already a round number, so this isn't it, but I've found: `getBoundingClientRect()` which seems to work well

Comment: @meowgoesthedog mind updating my fiddle to show me the example ? I tried what you just said but seems like I maybe didn't understood well

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I added an answer with correctly working code and an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two sources of error:

1. *(Minor)* Rounding of the angle. (Don't know what you meant by "already a round number")
2. *(Major)* You use the result of `getRotationDegrees` directly in `Math.cos / sin`. These functions require *radians*, i.e. the result directly returned by `Math.atan2`.

---

The snippet below adds the other two edges of the bounding box, and also the correct positional offset. I added a slider to change the rotation angle, in order to illustrate that this code is robust.

```js
function getMatrix(obj) {
   var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
                obj.css("-moz-transform") ||
                obj.css("-ms-transform") ||
                obj.css("-o-transform") ||
                obj.css("transform");
   return (matrix == 'none') ? null : matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
}

// calculate rotation angle of shape
function getRotationRadians(matrix) {
   var angle = matrix ? Math.atan2(matrix[1], matrix[0]) : 0;
   if (angle < 0) angle += 2.0 * Math.PI;
   return angle;
}

// calculate translation
function getTranslation(matrix) {
   return matrix ? [matrix[4], matrix[5]] : [0, 0];
}

// calculate bounding box
function getBoundingBox(shape) {
   var shapeLeft = shape.position().left,
       shapeTop = shape.position().top,
       shapeWidth = shape.width(),
       shapeHeight = shape.height();
       
   var matrix = getMatrix(shape);
   
   var angle = getRotationRadians(matrix);
   var height = Math.abs(shapeWidth * Math.sin(angle)) + Math.abs(shapeHeight * Math.cos(angle));
   var width = Math.abs(shapeHeight * Math.sin(angle)) + Math.abs(shapeWidth * Math.cos(angle));

   var trans = getTranslation(matrix);
   var left = trans[0] - (width * 0.5);
   var top = trans[1] - (height * 0.5);
   
   return {'x': left, 'y': top, 'w': width, 'h': height};
}

formatBox($('.shape'));

function formatBox(shape) {
   var box = getBoundingBox(shape);
     
   var offx = 124, offy = 109;

   var g1 = $('#g1'), g2 = $('#g2'), g3 = $('#g3'), g4 = $('#g4');

   g1.css('width', box.w);
   g2.css('height', box.h);
   g3.css('width', box.w);
   g4.css('height', box.h);

   g1.css('left', offx + box.x);
   g2.css('left', offx + box.x);
   g3.css('left', offx + box.x);
   g4.css('left', offx + box.x + box.w);

   g1.css('top', offy + box.y);
   g2.css('top', offy + box.y);
   g3.css('top', offy + box.y + box.h);
   g4.css('top', offy + box.y);
}
    
var angleInp = document.getElementById("angleInp");
angleInp.addEventListener("change", function() {
   var shape = $('.shape');
   shape.css('transform', 'rotate(' + angleInp.value + 'deg)');
   formatBox(shape);
}, false);
```

```css
.elements,
.element {
  position: absolute
}

#s2 {
  background: #333333;
  top: 60px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
   <input class="bar" type="range" id="angleInp" min="0" max="360" value="15" onchange="angleInp.value=value"/>
</div>
<div class="layout" style="position:relative; margin-top:50px; margin-left:70px;">
  <div class="elements">
    <div id="g1" class="element" style="background:red;left:0px;top:0px;height:2px;"></div>
    <div id="g2" class="element" style="background:red;left:0px;top:0px;width:2px;"></div>
    <div id="g3" class="element" style="background:red;left:0px;top:0px;height:2px;"></div>
    <div id="g4" class="element" style="background:red;left:0px;top:0px;width:2px;"></div>
    
    <div id="s2" class="element shape" style="transform: rotate(15deg);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```